# Render Map<String,Object> in freemarker table

Tags: java, spring-mvc, freemarker

I am getting error while rendering Map to freemarker template table.
below is the map what i am getting from controller with actual values.

```
Map<Object, Object> hramonths ={4={id=4, empjoindate=16 Nov 2007, description=Apr-2012, editable=T}, 5={id=5, empjoindate=16 Nov 2007, description=May-2012, editable=T}, 6={id=6, empjoindate=16 Nov 2007, description=Jun-2012, editable=T}, 7={id=7, empjoindate=16 Nov 2007, description=Jul-2012, editable=T}, 8={id=8, empjoindate=16 Nov 2007, description=Aug-2012, editable=T}, 9={id=9, empjoindate=16 Nov 2007, description=Sep-2012, editable=T}, 10={id=10, empjoindate=16 Nov 2007, description=Oct-2012, editable=T}, 11={id=11, empjoindate=16 Nov 2007, description=Nov-2012, editable=T}, 12={id=12, empjoindate=16 Nov 2007, description=Dec-2012, editable=T}, 1={id=1, empjoindate=16 Nov 2007, description=Jan-2013, editable=T}, 2={id=2, empjoindate=16 Nov 2007, description=Feb-2013, editable=T}, 3={id=3, empjoindate=16 Nov 2007, description=Mar-2013, editable=T}}
```

from my controller  now i want to render this values to my freemarker template like

```
<#list hramonths as indication>
                <tr>
                    <td class="center">
                        <#list monthlyrent as rent>
                            <#if indication.id == rent.month><input type="hidden" name="locationIndicatorId_${indication.id}" value="${indication.id}" /> </#if>
                        </#list>    
                    </td>
                    <td class="center">
                        ${indication.description}  <input type="hidden" name="month_${indication.id}" id="month_${indication.id}" value="${indication.id}" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="center">
                        <# assign varIndicatorId ="">
                        <#list monthlyrent as rent>
                            <#if indication.id == rent.month>
                                <# assign varIndicatorId = ${rent.Indicator}>
                            </#if>
                        </#list>                    
                        <select name="indicator_${indication.id}" <#if indication.editable == "F"> disabled="true" </#if> <#if editable == false>disabled="true"</#if>>
                            <#list indicators as indicator>
                                <option value="${indicator.cid}" <#if indicator.cid == varIndicatorId> selected </#if>>
                                    ${indicator.description}
                                </option>
                            </#list>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td class="right">
                        <#if mothlyrentsize != "0"> 
                            <#list monthlyrent as rent>
                                <#if indication.id == rent.month>
                                    <input type="text" align="right" name="rent_${indication.id}_${rent.cid}" 
                                        value="$DelphiNumber.formatNumber("$!rent.rent")"  
                                        <#if indication.editable == "F"> 
                                        readonly="true" class="rbox" </#if> 
                                        <#if editable == false>
                                            readonly="true" class="rbox"
                                        </#if>
                                        <#if indication.editable != "F" && editable != false>
                                            onBlur="isnumeric(this.form,this),updateHRATotalAll(this.form,'blurtype')"
                                    </#if> />                           
                                </#if>
                            </#list>                    
                        <#else>
                            <input type="text" name="rent_${indication.id}_0" value="$DelphiNumber.formatNumber("0")" 
                                #if("$!indication.editable" == "F") 
                                readonly="true" class="rbox" #end 
                                #if($editable == false)
                                    readonly="true" class="rbox"
                                #end
                                style="TEXT-ALIGN: right"
                                #if("$!indication.editable" != "F" && $editable != false)
                                    onBlur="isnumeric(this.form,this),updateHRATotalAll(this.form,'blurtype')"  
                                #end >
                            </input>    
                        </#if>  
            </td>                               
        </tr>
    </#list>
```

but i am getting error

```
Expected collection or sequence. hramonths evaluated instead to freemarker.template.SimpleHash on line 199, column 40 in WEB-INF/classes/com/greytip/cougar/module/epayroll/v2/freemarker/salary/it-declaration.ftl. The problematic instruction: ---------- ==> list hramonths as indication [on line 199, column 33 in WEB-INF/classes/com/greytip/cougar/module/epayroll/v2/freemarker/salary/it-declaration.ftl] ----------  Java backtrace for programmers: ---------- freemarker.template.TemplateException: Expected collection or sequence. hramonths evaluated instead to freemarker.template.SimpleHash on line 199, column 40
```

How do i render it on a table please any one help me.

Answer (score 0):

Replace you `Map` with `List`. So it looks like:

```
List<Object> hramonths =[
    {id=4, empjoindate=16 Nov 2007, description=Apr-2012, editable=T}, 
    {id=5, empjoindate=16 Nov 2007, description=May-2012, editable=T}, 
    {id=6, empjoindate=16 Nov 2007, description=Jun-2012, editable=T}]
```

You can use get all values from map:

```
Collection<Object> hramonthsValues = hramonths.values();
```

Answer (score 0):

freemarker doesn't understand well when a Map uses something else than a String as a key.
Replacing your `Map<Object, Object>` by a `Map<String, Object>` may resolve your exception. But you will need to use a "name" attribute to uniquely identify your Object, and also as a key for the Map.